# PreparedStatement java закрытие при использование в конструкторе класса

Tags: java, dao, preparedstatement

Пример кода:

```
class StudentDAO extends AbstractDAO <Integer, Student> {

    private static final String SQL_SELECT_ALL_STUDENT = "SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, SECOND_NAME, BIRTH_DATE,ENTER_YEAR FROM STUDENT";
    private static final String SQL_SELECT_STUDENT_BY_ID = "SELECT FIRST_NAME, SECOND_NAME, BIRTH_DATE,ENTER_YEAR FROM STUDENT WHERE ID=?";
    private static final String SQL_SELECT_STUDENT_BY_LASTNAME ="SELECT id,FIRST_NAME,BIRTH_DATE,ENTER_YEAR FROM. STUDENT WHERE SECOND_NAME=?";
    private static final String SQL_DELETE_STUDENT_BY_ID = "DELETE FROM STUDENT WHERE ID =?";
    private static final String SQL_INSERT_STUDENT = "INSERT INTO STUDENT"+"(FIRST_NAME, SECOND_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, ENTER_YEAR)"+"VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement1;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatementSelectById;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatementfindAll;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatementDeleteStudentById;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatementInsertStudent;

    public StudentDAO(Connection connection) throws DAOException, SQLException {
        super(connection);
        try {
            preparedStatementInsertStudent =connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT_STUDENT);
            preparedStatement1 = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT_STUDENT_BY_LASTNAME);
            preparedStatementfindAll = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT_ALL_STUDENT);
            preparedStatementDeleteStudentById = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_DELETE_STUDENT_BY_ID);
            preparedStatementSelectById = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT_STUDENT_BY_ID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Трудности возникли в том, как закрыть `ps` при их использовании в конструкторе класса?

Comment: @a.chugunov  Тогда каким образом используя средства ее постоянно не закрывать пс при вызове метода дао класса.?

Comment: опишите в вопросе какие именно у вас трудности при закрытии PS

Comment: С каких пор "олени начали гулять в степи"? Так же и у Вас сударь, каким боком Вы вообще инициализируете коннекты в конструкторе? Вы не можете написать отдельные функции с инициализацией статементов  и их закрытием?